# How does Profile Rank and profile rank experience work in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Today's update apparently brought some new things, including a new ranking and exp system to each player's profile.

[image]

Now I'm curious.  How do I level up, and what's the maximum rank?  Does this affect competitive stats whatsoever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your progression in your matchmaking rank is uninfluenced by your 'experience rank' since your matchmaking rank is based on an elo system. However, winning rounds in competitive matchmaking does contribute directly to your experience rank. Playing casual, arms race, deathmatch, etc all award experience towards your xp rank, but none of these have any bearing on your matchmaking rank.

Answer (score 2):

As we can read on the official blog (http://blog.counter-strike.net/), this is just a new mod, but it won't change the matchmaking content and competitive rank.
On this page, we can see at least 9 ranks, but I think there will be more (http://www.counter-strike.net/operationbloodhound/)

However, it seems that your stats in Matchmaking could rank up you on this new rank. You will also need a rank 3 to particupate in match making from the new update.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit to the number of times I can increase my Profile Rank?

There is no limit. Regardless of how much you play, you can always continue to gain XP toward a new Rank.